# Discord.js sending embed in dm using a / command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code is simple, it should send a dm embed at the person choose by the user using the command (it is a test for a ban command but it is easier to no ban my alt to after dean him and rejoin with him).

There is my code :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('Send a private message to a selected user')
    .addUserOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('target')
        .setDescription('The member to send the message to')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('reason')
        .setDescription('The reason for sending the message'))
    .setDMPermission(false),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const target = interaction.options.getUser('target');
    if (!target) return interaction.reply({ content: "You must provide a target user with the 'target' option.", ephemeral: true });

    const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') || 'No reason provided';
    const owner = await interaction.guild.fetchOwner();
    if (!owner) return interaction.reply({ content: "I couldn't fetch the guild owner.", ephemeral: true });

    if (target.user === interaction.client.user) return interaction.reply({ content: "I can't send a message to myself.", ephemeral: true });

    const banEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(0x0099FF)
      .setTitle('Hello! ')
      .setAuthor({ name: `request by ${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }) })
      .setDescription(`You have been banned from ${interaction.guild}.`)
      .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: `If you think there's an error, please contact ${owner.user.username}#${owner.user.discriminator}.` },
        { name: '\u200B', value: `Reason: ${reason}` },
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'Have a good day !' });

    try {
      await target.send({ content: "hello", embed: banEmbed });
      interaction.reply({ content: "The message has been sent successfully.", ephemeral: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      interaction.reply({ content: "I couldn't send the message to the target user.", ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};
```

The code is working only if I add content not embedded, in that case it won't send the embed and if I don't put the content, it will just send the error :

```
DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:667:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/lib/internal/process/task_queues.js:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:464:14)
    at async REST.request (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:910:22)
    at async DMChannel.send (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:176:15)
    at async Object.execute (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/commands/test.js:41:7)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/Users/theophile/Desktop/test bot copie/index.js:71:3) {requestBody: {…}, rawError: {…}, code: 50006, status: 400, method: 'POST', …}
```

Comment: Typo: it should be embed**s**. And the embeds should be in an array. `embeds: [banEmbed]`

Comment: It work ! Thanks you very much. That was pretty easy and I'm sorry for bothering you